# To install unbuffer in OSX

Tags: macos, terminal, unix, homebrew, install

There is the terminal command `unbuffer` in Linux Redhat, for instance. 
I did not find it in homebrew.

How can you install unbuffer in OSX Yosemite 10.10.3?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`unbuffer` is part of the `expect` package:

```
brew install homebrew/dupes/expect
```

You may need to:

```
brew tap homebrew/dupes/expect
```

Before you can install it.

*UPDATE:* As of 2018 expect is available without prefix in homebrew, thus:

```
brew install expect
```

is all that is necessary.

Comment: I love expect! How did you find it out?

Comment: I searched for “unbuffer command” and found a [man page](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/unbuffer1.html) which told me the author was Don Libes.  Searched for “unbuffer Don Libes” and found [another man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/unbuffer.1.html) which said “This page is part of the `expect` (programmed dialogue with interactive programs) project”.  I then looked at the OS X man page for `except` and tried a few things out, and failed.  I then searched homebrew for `expect` and found there to be a package.  I installed it, et voila!

Comment: I also found that I needed to do this prior to executing unbuffer:
`export TCLLIBPATH="/usr/local/lib"`

I found that this:
`unbuffer ./run-math-tests.sh | tee results.txt`
which runs a node script with colorized output, put the expected color codes into the results.txt file, which showed up properly with `cat` in the standard bash for macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 ... [it's possible to brew install a newer bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28782394/how-to-get-osx-shell-script-to-show-colors-in-echo) but it was unneccessary for my needs.

Comment: Thanks! Any tips how to find it on Big Sur?

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work if you have `conda` installed. The solution for Linux is to install `expect` via `conda`, but that package only exists for Linux, not macOS. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1047900/unbuffer-stopped-working-months-ago